# call function in fragment using viewPager

Tags: kotlin, search, android-viewpager, fragment

I have 3 fragments in which, each one has a function for search.
in my MainActivity, I created a view pager and pass these fragments to it.
I also have an edit text in my MainActivity that gets user input. I want to pass this input to a function that is located in fragments. that function calls an API and does a search.
but I can't access to that fragment. how should I do?
in fact, I want to have a search page like what Instagram has.

Answer (score 0):

All fragments should have a modelView in common, you can add the search result to a var within the view. 
If they do not share a common model view AKA they are parts of a different MVC you can add a shared component a singleton that will hold the data, notice that you have sync mechanizem if you use this method.